# Using a double throw switch to split 240v circuit to two appliances. Does neutral need to be switched?

Tags: electrical, switch, 240v

I'm looking to add a switch to an existing 240v circuit to switch power between two appliances. Do I need a 2 pole switch and just have the neutral attached to both appliances or do I need a 3 pole switch and switch neutral.

Comment: You should never switch a neutral, nor a ground.  No point and dangerous. But from what it appears like you are attempting to do is sounding like a hack job.   Probably dangerous and not code legal.   Please edit your question to include more details as to what you are really trying to accomplish so that we can give you better answers.

Comment: @George Anderson   "You should never switch a neutral" - are you really sure?

Comment: @xeeka  Yes, even if on generator power all the neutrals should be connected. I see no point in interrupting  neutrals.  Maybe people smarter than me might chime in, but, again, I see no point in switching neutrals.

Comment: F.e. GFCIs for (sub-) panels must - at least in Europe - also switch off the neutral. The neutral contact opening has even a tiny delay in order to avoid dangerous voltages in case of asymmetry. Also many extension plugs do switch off both poles (hot and neutral) - if they have a switch.

Comment: @George Anderson   Maybe you mean "You should never switch neutral ALONE", i.e. without switching the corresponding hot leg(s)? That recommendation could be very useful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where is this? What is the current limit on the breaker? . . . 30 A? 40 A? . . . What are the two appliances you wish to power?

Comment: I agree that this sounds _very_ much like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). If you'll tell us more about the situation, we may be able to help you come up with a better solution than inventing something yourself. Including things like where in the world you are (code matters), what appliances you're trying to switch, and a picture of the outlet(s) in question and the breaker panel/customer unit will be very helpful.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson There are some exceptions to the switched neutral, such as a double-pole switch (cuts hot and neutral). You're right that you shouldn't switch the neutral with a single pole switch.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson You need to do it on portable generators, otherwise the system will have 2 neutral-ground bonds - one at the panel and one at the generator.  This means some neutral current will path via the grounding system at all times, which it's not rated for.  Also if the fat neutral-ground bond at the panel fails, all fault current paths through the dainty wiring to the generator. In case of a dead short, it would be a high resistance path that may limit flow - too little for the breaker to instant-trip but enough to set the N and G wires on fire.

Comment: Yes, OP do you realize you are allowed to have any number of receptacles on a 15-30A circuit?  You don't necessarily need a nanny switch.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to switch all 3 poles in that case.

In case of defects or a lose neutral connection in the incoming supply line, the neutral could have a dangerous voltage, fed by the 240V appliance switched on, f.e.  in case of asymmetrical loads.

Even GGCIs would not necessarily trip in that case, since the sum of both hot legs plus neutral currents might be still 0.